# Help with a proof on asymptotic behaviour of the counting function of Markov Numbers (In Zagier's article)

Tags: analysis, number-theory, asymptotics

In this article (a pdf is easily findable online) Zagier gives an approximation of the number of Markoff number below a certain bound. What I struggle with is to show that if
\begin{equation}
E_{\alpha,\beta}(x) = \frac{3x^2}{\pi^2\alpha\beta} + O\left( \frac{x}{\alpha} \right) + 
O\left( \frac{x}{\beta} \log \frac{x}{\beta} \right) 
\end{equation}
And
\begin{equation}
E_{f(p),f(q)}(f(x)) \leq M_m(x) \leq E_{f(p)-\frac{c}{r^2},f(q)- \frac{c}{r^2} }(f(x))
\end{equation}
Then
\begin{equation}
M_m(x) = \frac{3f(x)^2}{\pi^2(f(p)+O(1/r^2)) (f(q)+O(1/r^2))}+ O\left( \frac{f(x)}{f(p)} \right) + 
O\left( \frac{f(x)}{f(q)} \log \frac{f(x)}{f(q)} \right) 
\end{equation}

Where $m=(p,q,r)$ is a Markoff triple, $f(x)=arccosh(3x/2)$ and c is a constant such that
\begin{equation}
f(r)<f(p)+f(q)<f(r)+\frac{c}{r^2}
\end{equation}

More details can be found in the article but I believe that this is enough.
Thanks a lot if you take time to help me.